# My javascript for loop is only printing 1 rows out of an array with 3 rows

Tags: javascript, for-loop, conditional-statements

I don't know what the right condition should be on a for loop that loops through an array that will have a varying length depending on how many rows are in a table that I pull from and add to the array.  The array currently has three rows, but the for loop only prints out two. My code:

```
//my database query 

query.find({
  success: function(results) {

//this for loop works fine

    for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++){

        eventID = results[i].id;
       activity = results[i].get("activity");
        scene = results[i].get("location");
        neighborhood = results[i].get("neighborhood");
        date = results[i].get("date");
        details = results[i].get("details");
        time = results[i].get("time");
        objIDs.push(eventID);

//each row gets pushed into an array

       search.push([activity, scene, neighborhood, date, details, time]);


        //I empty a div on a page that uses the ajax load() method to load an html page.I replace that html with the array of query results. 

             $('#div1').empty();

       //there are currently 3 rows in my array, but when I loop through it and append() the </br>rows to the div, only one gets printed. I've tried changing the comparison operator to </br>different things but nothing works. I'm definitely getting all the rows from the query because when I alert() the search array I see all the rows. 

       for (i = 0; i <= search.length; i++) {

            $('#mainDiv').append("<div id='event'>" + search[i].join(' ') + "<a href='#' class='interested'>Interested?</a></div>");
        } 

    };// closes for
    },//closes success

  error: function(error) {
    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
  }
}); //closes find
```

Comment: did you check if the query response is returning all object you need?

Comment: Where is `search` initialised? Are there really 3 rows in `search` or are there 3 rows in `results`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `for` inside a `for` your search has not been initialised completely when you iterate over it.

```
};// closes for

    for (i = 0; i <= search.length; i++) {

        $('#mainDiv').append("<div id='event'>" + search[i].join(' ') + "<a href='#' class='interested'>Interested?</a></div>");
    } 

},//closes success
```

Answer (score 2):

While the below is *a* problem, it might not be *the* problem. However, as I cannot delete this post (I must login or something?) it remains as an artifact. Please heed it, even if the problem is something else.

---

The code uses the same `i` variable in *nested* loops - and increments `i` in both loops.

Use a different variable.